# RTABMAP Navigation without providing a map

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I have been searching but haven't found out how the navigation stack works when no static map is given. My questions are:

1. Can Rtabmap be run without a static map? If yes, how is localization done?
2. How are you able to specify a goal position for the robot without a map?
3. How is global planning done without knowledge of the environment?

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381719/rtabmap-navigation-without-providing-a-map/) by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2021-07-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rtabmap` is a tool. It's not used for "standard" navigation. It's purpose is to **build** a map using sensors on the robot. Localization is often done by odometry from wheel encoders, or sometimes by gps when outdoors. It's an on-going research problem on how to correct the localization drift once enough data is gathered.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1